# Abrir y cerrar navbar lateral con un botón y que se corra el contenido de la pagina

Tags: javascript

Estoy creando una navbar lateral la cual quiero que se **abra y cierre con el mismo botón**. A la vez que al realizar esta acción el contenido de la pagina se desplace en este caso, hacia la derecha. Intente crear alguna función con *if else* y no he podido dar con la correcta.

```
<script>
function togNav(){
    var element = document.getElementById("nav");
    if (element.width == "250px") {
        element.style.width = "0";
    } else{
        element.style.width = "250px"
    }

}
</script>
```

Es lo que

Answer (score 0):

El problema radica en que estás accediendo mal a a la propiedad.

No todos los elementos del DOM contienen la propiedad width sobre la raíz del objeto, éste sólo existe cuando implictamente se estableció la propiedad sobre la etiqueta del HTML. Sólo lo podrías cambiar por estilo, si ya le estableciste una entonces sólo puede acceder a ella mediante la propiedad style.

Entonces quedaría así

```
<script>
function togNav(){
    var element = document.getElementById("nav");
    if (element.style.width == "250px") {
        element.style.width = "0";
    } else{
        element.style.width = "250px"
    }

}
</script>
```

Sin embargo, yo usaría un estado para saber si debería estar abierto o no.

```
<script>
// Estado inicial
var abierto = false;

function togNav(){
    var element = document.getElementById("nav");
    // Actualizamos el estado
    abierto = !abierto;

    !abierto ? 
       element.style.display = "none" :
        element.style.display = "inline-block"; // O tu propiedad deseada
}
</script>
```

Comment: Sinceramente no entendí jajaja, soy nuevo con js y no estoy muy familiarizado con los conceptos que podrían ser básicos. Yo solo quiero que mi hamburguesa abra y cierre mi nav -.-